# Assume that $2n-1$, $2m-1$,$m+n$ are primes for some $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\frac{m^n+n^m}{m+n}$ and $\frac{m^m+n^n}{m+n}$ are not integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that $2n-1$, $2m-1$, $m+n$ are primes for some $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $\frac{m^n+n^m}{m+n}$ and $\frac{m^m+n^n}{m+n}$ are not integers.

---

One has to prove, that $m^n+n^m$ and $m^m+n^n$ are not divisible by a prime number $m+n$, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: there may me a reason for specifically these two numbers are in the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $2m-1$ and $2n-1$ are assumed to be prime, it follows that $m,n \geqslant 2$. Since $m+n$ is assumed to be prime, it then follows that one of $m,n$ is even and the other is odd.

Let $k = m-n$ and $p := m+n$. Then

$$\gcd (k,p-1) = \gcd (k, p+k-1) = \gcd (k, 2m-1) \mid 2m-1$$

and

$$\gcd (k,p-1) = \gcd (k, p-k-1) = \gcd (k,2n-1) \mid 2n-1,$$

hence $\gcd (k,p-1) \mid \gcd (2m-1,2n-1) = 1$.

Now choose the naming of $m$ and $n$ such that $n$ is odd. Then $p \mid m^n + n^n$, so

$$p \mid m^m + n^n \iff p \mid m^n - m^m.$$

Write $\lvert m^n - m^m\rvert = m^{\min \{m,n\}}\bigl(m^{\lvert k\rvert} - 1\bigr)$. Since $1 < m < p$, we know that $p \nmid m^{\min \{m,n\}}$, and since $\gcd(k,p-1) = 1$ we have $p \mid a^{\lvert k\rvert} - 1 \iff p \mid a-1$. But $p \nmid m-1$, and thus we can deduce $p \nmid m^m + n^n$.

The argument for $p \nmid m^n + n^m$ is similar.